# Element relative to specific Image point which is background-size : cover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background-image

I have a scenario like below:

```css
.cover-image {
background : no-repeat url('https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/536575/164027042/stock-photo-simple-and-stylish-office-environment-164027042.jpg') center center / cover; 
  height : 100vh;
  width : 100vw;
  position : absolute;
  z-index : 1;
  left : 0;
}
body{margin : 0; padding : 0; }
.data{
position:absolute;
 position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    top: 61vh;
    left: 11vw;
    background: red;  
}
.container {
position : absolute; height : 100vh; width : 100vw; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class='cover-image'></div>
<div class='data'>chair</div>
</div>
```

Here the Data box should always be at left top of chair, If we resize the window.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What is it doing wrong right now that you would like to change? Would you like the box to change size with picture?

Comment: @MichaelBruce , If I resize the window then the box should be relative to image, means the box should be at the left top of chair at any window size.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not applying the image as the body's background? Also, as of your current code, when resizing the window, the image won't change. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to accomplish that, but taking your existing code and make it work, the following seems to be the solution for your scenario. 
Note that you will have to play around with the correct sizing, this is just the idea. (You can see a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/unv9vgau/) here).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="cover-image">
   </div>

   <div class="data">Chair</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.container{
   width: 1000px;
}

.cover-image { 
   background : no-repeat url('https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/536575/164027042/stock-photo-simple-and-stylish-office-environment-164027042.jpg') center center / cover;  
   float: left;
   height: 942px;
   width: 1920px;  
}

.data { 
   margin-right: 20%;
   background-color: red;
   float: right;
   height: 30px;
   width: 40px;
   margin-top:580px;
   margin-left: 170px;
   position: absolute;
}
```